# automatically refresh a checkpoint vpn connection when it's expiring

Tags: vpn, checkpoint-endpoint

I need to connect to a checkpoint vpn from a script, and then perform some operation.

I'm using Check Poin Endpoint Security on windows to connect my pc to the vpn of my company. With the GUI it works well, but now I need to automate the connection for performing nightly tasks, so I need to write a script that connects to the vpn, make the work and then it disconnects itself from vpn.

I'm connecting to checkpoint vpn with following command:

```
.\trac.exe connect -s "MyConnection" -u "MyUsername" -p "MyPassword"
```

It works, but my vpn account is configured to log-out after some hours. With the GUI I've a warning telling me that the connection it's expiring, and I need to click a button in order to refresh the connection and continue to use it without any disconnection. How can I do the same thing from the command line in automatic way? I don't want to disconnect from vpn before my operations are completed.

Comment: To extend the time-limit, see [this post](https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/Remote-Access-VPN/How-to-increase-VPN-timeout-limits/m-p/26122#) and especially the answer by Timothy_Hall toward the end.

Comment: I cannot modify the server, I just need to find a way to extend the session in the client, since I can do it in the GUI by pressing a button...

Comment: I don't know how to do that. However, as you're on Windows, I do know how to automate the click...